# What is the equivalent of cocoa touch frameworks on android devices?

Tags: java, android, ios, cocoa-touch

In iOS development there is an underlying framework known as Cocoa and Cocoa Touch which has helped tremendously in getting more accustomed to object oriented programming.  I'm curious to know, since Android is typically written in Java which is object oriented, are there frameworks for Android that are equivalent to Cocoa or Cocoa Touch?  If so, what are they known as or called?

Comment: *more accustomed*?? What does it mean?

Comment: It means I can see how design patterns apply towards creating the structure of my application using Cocoa or Cocoa Touch frameworks.  They are available to me to use in order to create app without starting total from scratch.  I figured Android must follow the same principles because it comes from the "C" programming language family.  So I was hoping there were frameworks similar to the approach Cocoa Touch has for iOS.

Comment: Mmmmh I have never seen something like that but I can not say it does not exist, may be I just do not know...

Answer (score 0):

I would say **none** because Android and iOS are two different platforms.

From the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html) archive:

> Cocoa is an application environment for both the OS X operating system
> and iOS, the operating system used on Multi-Touch devices such as
> iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. It consists of a suite of
> object-oriented software libraries, a runtime system, and an
> integrated development environment.

In short, Cocoa is a suite of OO libraries, runtime system and IDE.

In contrast, Android has its own OO software libraries in the android platform packages (Views, Context, Activities, Fragments, etc..). Android also has its own Dalvik Runtime and Android Runtime (ART). For the IDE, Android's official IDE is Android Studio which is created and maintained by a different company (Jetbrains).